# calculating the integral of $x^{2n+2}e^{-\lambda x^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I am asked to show that: $$ 4\sqrt{\frac{\lambda^3}{\pi}} \int_0^\infty  x^{2n+2}e^{-\lambda x^2} \ dx = \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot \dots \cdot (2n+1)}{(2\lambda)^n}$$ given that I know $$4\sqrt{\frac{\lambda^3}{\pi}} \int_0^\infty  x^{3}e^{-\lambda x^2} \ dx = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi\lambda}}$$

I let $I_n = \int_0^\infty  x^{2n+2}e^{-\lambda x^2} \ dx$ and I used integration by parts to get $I_n = \frac{2n+1}{2\lambda}I_{n-1}$, so I get $$I_n = \dfrac{(2n+1) \cdot \dots \cdot 3}{(2\lambda)^{n-1}}I_0$$ and I calculate $I_0 = \frac{1}{4\lambda^2}$ I am not sure how to use what they give me, and why I am oging wrong please help

Comment: I don't suppose you know about the [gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html)?

Comment: I do, but it is not used on this course so I want to avoid it.

Comment: Something's wrong, since $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{2n+2}e^{-x}\,dx = (2n+2)!.$$

Comment: Maybe $e^{-\lambda x}$ was intended to be $e^{-\lambda x^2}$? That makes sense, since it explains the $\sqrt{\pi}$ factor, too.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio yes sorry ill edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may get rid of the $\lambda$ parameter through a suitable substitution, so the problem boils down to proving that:
$$ J(n) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} x^{2n+2} e^{-x^2}\,dx = \frac{(2n+1)!!}{2^{n}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}.\tag{1}$$
We may check that $J(0)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}$. Integration by parts gives:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} J(n+1)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} x^{2n+4}e^{-x^2}\,dx &=& \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{2}\,x^{2n+3}\cdot 2x e^{-x^2}\,dx\\&=&\frac{2n+3}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{2n+2}e^{-x^2}\,dx\\&=&\frac{2n+3}{2}\cdot J(n)\end{eqnarray*} $$
so $(1)$ easily follows by induction.

Comment: How does this use the given integral the question has given us?

Comment: @lampj20la: read the first line and use the substitution $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}z$. The problem gives the value of my $J(1)$.

Comment: could I ask, how do you know the fraction $\frac{2n+1}{2\lambda}\frac{2n-1}{2\lambda}\dots\frac{3}{2\lambda}$ has $n$ terms? so that we get $(2\lambda)^n$?

Comment: @lampj20la: I do not need it. I have $J(0)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}$ and $J(n+1)=\frac{2n+3}{2}\cdot J(n)$, so $J(n)=\frac{(2n+1)!!}{2^n}\cdot J(0)$. I got rid of $\lambda$ at the very beginning.

Comment: thanks but I was asking in general

Comment: @lampj20la: Then your question has nothing to do with my answer. Anyway, it is trivial that $(2n+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot 3$ is the product of $n$ terms, since the smallest is $2\cdot\color{red}{1}+1$ and the largest is $2\cdot\color{red}{n}+1$.